# Question on how to prove that a vector space is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a past exam question that wasn't explained in my lecture notes:

> For vector spaces $U$ and $V$ over the same field of scalars $\mathbb{F}$
>
> Let $U = V = P^{25}$ the space of real polynomial functions of degree up to $25$. Verify that the mapping $ϕ$ sending $f ∈ P^{25}$ to $(x+3)\frac{df}{dx}+2$  is linear.

What on earth does this question mean and how do i solve it?

Comment: It means what it says. You have a map given and it asks you to show that this map is linear. Now look up what the term linear means.

Comment: It means that for any $f,g\in P^{25}$, it holds that $\phi(f+g)=\phi(f)+\phi(g)$ and $\phi(\lambda f)=\lambda\phi(f)$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Using the properties of the derivative, this should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

consider
$$
\phi(f+\alpha g)=(x+3)\frac{d}{dx}(f+\alpha g)+2
$$
where $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$ and verify if it is an element of $P^{25}$ if $f,g \in P^{25}$ and if it is the same as:
$$
\phi(f)+\alpha \phi(g)=(x+3)\frac{df}{dx}+2+\alpha[(x+3)\frac{dg}{dx}+2 ]
$$

This proves linearity.